# Javascript Image() doesn't load or draw

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, onload

I'm trying to create a simple Sprite class for use in a canvas game, but the image I specify when I create a new instance of the class never calls onload or onerror.
What's happening, and how do I get it to load and draw the image?

Here's the script:

```
var cvs = document.getElementById("c");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");
var imagesToLoad = 1 ;
var imagesLoaded = 0;
var gameState = 0;
//START OF IMAGE STUFF//
function imageOnload() {
    imagesLoaded+=1;
    console.log("Images: loaded "+imagesLoaded+" overall.");
}
function loadLoop() {
    if (imagesLoaded == imagesToLoad) {
        gameState = 1;
    }
}
function loop1() {
    ctx.drawImage(circle.image);
}
function gameLoop() {
    if(gameState==0){
        loadLoop();
    }
    if(gameState==1){
        loop1();
    }
}

function Sprite(positionsArray){
    this.x = positionsArray[0];
    this.y = positionsArray[1];
    this.dx = positionsArray[2];
    this.dy = positionsArray[3];
    this.angle = positionsArray[4];
    this.rotating = positionsArray[5];


};
circle = new Sprite(new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0));
circle.image = new Image().onload="imageOnload()".src="circle.png".onerror="console.log(\"Nope.\")";
console.log("circle?");
setInterval(function(){gameLoop()}, 10);
//END OF IMAGE STUFF//
```

Comment: Wow look at that one liner...

Comment: Let me start with some pointers. Use `imagesLoaded++`, since it's a character less than `imagesLoaded+=1`. You don't have to write `new Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)` in JavaScript, just use `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. The `Image` Object fires `.onload()` after the `.src` has fully loaded into your cache, like `var img = new Image(); img.src = 'where.png'; img.onload = function(){/* now do your thing */}`. Why are trying to assign an `Image` to a single instance of your `Sprite` Constructor?

Comment: Please do not edit in your answer to the question. Post an answer yourself if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections:

- No quotes on image.onload function definition
- No parens on image.onload function definition
- image.onerror requires a function definition or anonymous function
- Put image.onerror before image.src

Here's some example code:

```
circle.image=new Image();
circle.image.onload=imageOnLoad;
circle.image.onerror=function(){console.log("Image failed to load")};
circle.image.src="koolaidman.png";

function imageOnLoad(){
    ctx.drawImage(circle.image,0,0);  // or do other stuff
}
```